# Hiding A Button Based on Exact URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uibutton, hidden

I'm trying to hide a button only when a certain URL is being displayed in a `UIWebView`. This is the code I'm using to do so:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    NSString *host = [request.URL host];
    if ([host isEqualToString:@"http://example.com/cheese"]) {
        _backButton.hidden = YES;
    } else {
        _backButton.hidden = NO;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I test it to see if the back button is hidden, it never is. It stays in plain view whether "example.com/cheese" is loaded or not. (That /cheese part is pretty important as well, maybe it is only checking the host and not the full URL?)

Either way, I have no idea what to change or add to get this working. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Update**: I added in an NSLog just before the `if` statement, and it's not even firing. I also changed the code to the answer below (thanks again rmaddy). I have no idea why this method is not firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `host` part of the URL is just that, the host. If the URL is:

> http://example.com/cheese

then the `host` is just `example.com`.

If you want to compare the full URL then do this:

```
NSString *full = [request.URL absoluteString];
if ([full isEqualToString:@"http://example.com/cheese"]) {
}
```

If you want to compare just the host then do this:

```
NSString *host = [request.URL host];
if ([host isEqualToString:@"example.com"]) {
}
```

What's odd is that you have it correct in the second bit of code you posted. It is wrong in the first bit of code you posted.

Also, in the first block of code, you call `return 0` at the end. You should return either `YES` or `NO` since the return type is `BOOL`.

Comment: Brilliant, that helped out a lot for my other method! Thank you. But, I changed my first method, the one that hides the buttons, to look for the full URL and it still doesn't hide the button when example.com/cheese is loaded. I double checked and made sure its outlet is connected. I also changed it to `return YES`.

Comment: I threw a `return YES;` in the `if` and a `return NO;` in the else, and it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why don't you look at the actual URL and see what it is. It may not be what you think it is. Add an NSLog statement or use the debugger to view the value just before the `if` statement.

Comment: I added the NSLog just before the `if` statement, and it won't even fire. Very odd. I did make sure though that the URL is completely correct though.